# pasar function a arrow

Tags: javascript

[image: Necesito que esto declarado sea pasado a arrow]

en el cual yo pongo lo siguiente, y me tira un error el cual se ve en la imagen

```js
let saludar = (nombre, apellido) => "Hola, " + nombre + apellido + "!";
console.log(saludar("Juan", " Perez"));
```

Comment: ¿No falta el espacio en blanco entre `nombre` y `apellido`?

Comment: El espacio no lo tenes que poner en `apellido`, lo tenes que concatenar entre las variables

Comment: O mejor aun, usar un string template: `\`Hola, ${nombre} ${apellido}!\``. Son más fáciles de leer que concatenar strings con el `+` y más rápidos, todo ventajas.